# Which Maven goal to use as no-op (for scripting purposes)?

Tags: maven, plugins

I have a script on Jenkins CI which optionally does dependency:go-offline. The other option should be to do nothing. But I can't put "" in there - it must be a goal.

So - which one would you pick? It should:

- Be in central, always reachable
- Take minimum time
- Have minimal output
- Have no side effects

I was thinking of some help:... goal but those tend to have a lot of output. Any better?

Comment: Why are doing via script go-offline and using mvn -o option? And for what purposes?

Comment: go-offline ensures downloading all necessary dependencies, even those which are not downloaded without it. Mostly plugin deps. Not sure about the mechanisms behind it. The purpose is to be able to build on other machine which does not have access to the repository on our company's VPN.

Comment: Hm. Building without repository access in Maven does not make sense. May be i don't see the point..

Comment: It does, in enterprise business productization. Imagine a project with 1500 dependencies from dozens of sources.

Comment: If you dozens of sources you should use your internal repository manager. I really don't see the point. Is this a kind of deployment to production? If yes than this is not a job for Maven.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use this goal and option:

```
mvn --quiet help:help
```

the `-q`,`--quiet` option causes the output to only show errors.

Note that Jenkins allows you to add options like `--quiet` as diplayed in the usage: `mvn [options] [<goal(s)>]`. You configure these in the Jenkins job’s “Goals and options” field.

Check `mvn --help` output for further information.

I know this is an old question, but I came across it when I had the same requirement and it's still unanswered, so I'm posting for anyone who needs it in future.

Comment: Even help:help downloads stuff. Would be nice if there was truly a noop goal. For example, `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version` doesn't need to download anything to pull the version from the root pom file...but the command takes forever since it still downloads lots of...stuff

Answer (score 0):

This still depends on the current project, but could be useful if you don't want to hardcode a specific plugin for some reason:

```
mvn -pl ./ validate
```

`-pl ./` means only current project, ignore submodules. Alternatively you could specify specific project by relative path or `[groupId]:artifactId`.
`validate` is the first phase of the [Default Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). Doesn't change or build anything.

Alternatively, if you don't have a maven project at all, some maven plugins, or rather specific plugin goals, can be executed without it. E.g.:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:help
```

It would still scan projects if it sees a POM in the current directory. And of course you still need to have the plugin in your local repository.